# Specifying maven nar plugin compiler and linker executable paths

Tags: ios, maven

I need to specify the full path to the compiler executable for building with maven-nar.

The aol.properties file seems to only accept certain predefined values for the compiler name.

How do I tell the nar plugin exactly where my compiler and linker executables are. In this case I am trying to compile for ios from macosx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the only way is to add the compiler to CppTasks and install the 'hacked' version on your build host.
Here is the version I would use as a starting point: http://duns.github.com/maven-nar-plugin/cpptasks.html

Comment: Looks like this is the only solution. The plugin only supports its hardcoded list of compilers. Additionally we found that the plugin butchers the command line parameters that you pass to the compiler in the aol.properties file.

Answer (score 1):

There is starting to be some effort to merge the NAR branches
https://github.com/maven-nar/maven-nar-plugin

Would be worthwhile raising issues there.

For Windows 32/64 bit support different compiler paths where needed if wanting to run maven once without changing environment variables to build both platforms.

There is a work in progress, been using for a while, but not really published it.  I'm using windows only and never tried it on mac.

https://github.com/GregDomjan/maven-nar-plugin/tree/multi

I was aiming to merge it with trunk and have not had a chance yet to load the matching cpptasks changes required to allow provision of the path and some other settings.
Unfortunatly there where also a bunch of other changes that may be uncessary around configuration.